# SSRS Header report item value in report body

Tags: reporting-services

Can anybody please tell me how can I get the value of report header text box in report body. I tried referring the report header report item into body, but I got an error.

Comment: What's the expression? Any reason you can't just use the same in the body textbox?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. You can go the other way only, and even thst requires shared code